# Different behavior of rjust with strings vs numpy strings

Tags: python, string, numpy

I am seeing a difference in behavior in rjust() when used on a string vs on a numpy string.

My goal is to fill a number string with 0s. I am seeing a difference in behavior when calling rjust on a string vs a numpy string.

I am running this on google colab.

```
# Call rjust to fill with zeros to a width of 5. 
# rjust doesnt truncate if strlen is greater than the width parameter

print("12".rjust(5,'0'))
print("12345".rjust(5,'0'))
print("12345678".rjust(5,'0'))

inp_arr = np.array(["12", "12345", "12345678"])

# Calling rjust on a numpy string truncates the string if it is longer than width
print(inp_arr, np.char.rjust(inp_arr, 5, "0"))
```

---

00012
12345
12345678
['12' '12345' '12345678'] ['00012' '12345' '12345']

---

Notice the string "12345678" has different output in the two cases. With numpy.char.rjust it got truncated whereas with str.rjust it didn't.

What am I doing wrong. I don't want it to truncate.

Comment: You know how to achieve what you want and you know how to achieve truncation. So what is your problem? That you don't like the solution? That you think it shouldn't be the way it is?

Comment: @Claudio OP is interested to know if possible why numpy behaves differently. ie might be perceived as inconsistent/incorrect results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1

```
result_arr = np.core.defchararray.rjust(inp_arr, 5, "0")
print(result_arr)
```

output: ['00012' '12345' '12345']
read about the function on : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.rjust.html

Solution 2

```
#Apply rjust to each element
vectorized_rjust = np.vectorize(lambda s: s.rjust(5, "0"))
result2 = vectorized_rjust(inp_arr)
```

output: ['00012' '12345' '12345678']

Comment: @cem-kocak Thanks. That worked. I am still new to python/numpy. Claudio - yes my concern was why the behavior is different. The string rjust documentation says that if the string is longer than the width, then the original string (longer) is returned.

Comment: @kmaps : be prepared that using Python and its libraries (or any other programming language and its libraries) you will run into next examples of inconsistencies. It is as it is, so intuition might work in many cases, but generally don't rely on it and always check the details of the documentation first before using a function/method/operator. Remember: same function/method name or same operator symbol do not guarantee the same behavior ( e.g. `2*pyListObj` behaves different to `2*npArrayOFpyListObj`) .

Comment: @kmaps since you said my solution has worked can you pick this answer as the accepted answer (check mark button) so the question can be concluded. Not obligated but it would be nice if you did :)

Comment: Just did. Sorry I'm new here and still learning the etiquette.

Comment: @kmaps No problem at all my friend :) I wish you a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [644]: alist = ["12", "12345", "12345678"]; arr = np.array(alist); arr
Out[644]: array(['12', '12345', '12345678'], dtype='<U8')
```

`numpy` string arrays have a `dtype` with a specified max string length.  That's because elements in the array are all stored in the same `nbytes`.  A python list stores pointers to string objects stored else where in memory.

```
In [645]: arr.astype('U5')
Out[645]: array(['12', '12345', '12345'], dtype='<U5')
```

Trying to put a longer string into a given dtype will result in truncation.

`rjust` applied to the elements of the list:

```
In [646]: [str.rjust(5,"0") for str in alist]
Out[646]: ['00012', '12345', '12345678']
```

and if we wrap that list in an array:

```
In [647]: np.array([str.rjust(5,"0") for str in alist])
Out[647]: array(['00012', '12345', '12345678'], dtype='<U8')
```

`np.char.rjust`  returns the 'U5' dtype:

```
In [648]: np.char.rjust(arr, 5,"0")
Out[648]: array(['00012', '12345', '12345'], dtype='<U5')

In [649]: np.char.rjust(arr, 8,"0")
Out[649]: array(['00000012', '00012345', '12345678'], dtype='<U8')
```

The docs for `np.char.rjust` specifies:

```
width : int
    The length of the resulting strings
```

That's different from `rjust` method.  While not explicit as it could be, it does hint at this truncation.

`np.char` functions apply the corresponding string methods to each element of the array.  `numpy` doesn't do any of its own 'native' string manipulation, so the `char` functions are not any faster than the equivalent list comprehension.  So if the `hp.char` function doesn't do what you want, don't use it.

`np.vectorize` was suggested as an alternative.  It too has a speed disclaimer.  For small arrays it tends to be slower than the list comprehension, but scales better for larger arrays.